# Angular Directive attributes contain additional properties

Tags: angularjs

I've created a custom directive which uses the element's attributes to build a string. When I enumerate the link function's `attrs` parameter I found it also contains angular properties `$$element` and `$attr`. What is the purpose of these? Currently I'm having to filter these out like so:

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);
app.directive('imgTransform', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<img src="{{uri}}" alt="{{title}}" />',
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {


            angular.forEach(attrs, function (value, key) {
                if (key.charAt(0) !== '$') {
                }
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Attributes docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile.directive.Attributes):

> A shared object between directive compile / linking functions which contains normalized DOM element attributes

This object is more than just a key value hashmap, it also has methods that it inherits from the **Attributes class** through it's prototype. The reason why it has the **$attrs** and **$$elements** properties is to give the right context (element/attributes) to these methods   :

```
this.$$elements
this.$attr
```

*BTW, every property with a $$-prefix in angular.js is an undocumented private property, and should not be used externally. javascript doesn't support real private methods/properties so angular uses this convention.*

#### See this example:

[image]

Looking further in the docs:

> #### $attr
>
> object: A map of DOM element attribute names to the normalized name. This is needed to do reverse lookup from normalized name back to actual name.

#### Fortunately, you can use `attrs.$attr` like so:

```
 angular.forEach(attrs.$attr, function (value, key) {
    attrs[key] // <---
```